# Mac OS 10.5 Server Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, mac, mac-osx

After editing the default virtual host in OSX server, whenever I attempt to access the site I get a message:

> Access forbidden!
>   You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

I didn't change any permissions. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the webroot for that vhost is an empty folder and indexes are not on.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommended recreating it in a new directory, and ensure permissions are correct.